# Is there a way to make a subset of the most frequently occuring elements in a dataset in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking to make a plot of the frequencies of the ten most common dog breeds in an excel csv data set with hundreds of dog breeds in it.  Is there any way to do this?

[image]

```
getwd()
   
library(datasets)  
library(ggplot2)

pacman::p_load(pacman, rio,ggplot2) 


dogSample <- import("C:/Users/casey/OneDrive/Desktop/Rtest/samples.csv")
head(dogSample)
summary(dogSample)
breedbars<-table(dogSample$Breed)
genders<-table(dogSample$Gender)


plot(breedbars,
        
        xlab="Breeds",
        ylab="frequency",
        main="Numbers of breeds",
        
        )
```

Comment: You bet! It will be much easier for people to give specific help if you can make your question reproducible. Can you provide some sample data and any code you've tried?

Comment: Thanks!  I just edited my main post to have the code I'm using and a picture of the data set I made

Comment: you just need to sort the table and select the number you want `barplot(sort(breedbars, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]])`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic approach given a common dataset, `diamonds`, included with `ggplot2`, part of the `tidyverse` meta-package.

Here, I take the `diamonds` dataset, count the number of rows by the number of times each `cut` appears (as `n`), only keep the first 5 most common, then change my cut variable to be an ordered factor that is ordered by `n`, and finally plot that as a horizontal bar plot, with n on the x axis and the cut on the y axis.

The only step you'd need to add is to load the csv, for which there are many online tutorials, like here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>%
  count(cut, sort = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  mutate(cut = fct_reorder(cut, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = cut)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just updated my original post to include my code and my data set.  With the code you provided I'm getting an error stating  "Error in UseMethod("count") : 
  no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "table"".   Do you know what the problem could be?